Perfect transitive groups in $Sym(n)$
Is there any way to classify all perfect transitive subgroups of $Sym(n)$?
When I say transitive I refer with respect to the natural action of $Sym(n)$ on $\{1, ..., n\}$. I also remind that a group $G$ is perfect if $G = G'$ or if its abelianization is trivial.
At the beginning I believed that the only group with these characteritics was the alternating group $A_n$, but if $q$ is an odd prime power then $SL(m,q)$ is also perfect so there are other perfect transitive groups in $n = q^m-1$.

Well every (perfect) group is transitive on itself, so I guess you want to fix $n$?

Even if you restricted to primitive subgroups of $S-n$, you would be looking for all maximal subgroups of all perfect groups. But primitive groups have been enumerated up to $n=8191$.

Sorry Steve, I meant with respect to the natural action on {1,...,n}. I added what action I refer to now.

Steve's comment is correct. Every perfect group $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_{|G|}$.

I see, I had not thought about that. I was thinking with n fixed, but after that comment it looks hard to say something.
